# facebook how to <fb:visible-to-connection> problem?

Tags: php, html, facebook, fbml

```
<fb:visible-to-connection>
<img src="http://www.xxx.com/images/welcome1.jpg" border="0" alt="Welcome to ">
<fb:else>
<div style="top: 0; position: absolute;">
<img src="http://www.xxx.com/images/like_us1.jpg" />
</div>
</fb:else>
</fb:visible-to-connection>
```

this code works fine if i use it inside facebook FBML tab app.

but i have another app that uses iframes and i'm loading a simple page from my website. Im trying to put my html/php code together with the fbml one but with no success:

```
<html>
<dody>
<fb:visible-to-connection>
..........html and php code here........
<fb:else>
<div style="top: 0; position: absolute;">
<img src="http://www.xxx.com/images/like_us1.jpg" />
</div>
</fb:else>
</fb:visible-to-connection>
</body>
</html>
```

something like this, but it wont really work,

any suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/customizing-facebook-iframe-application-signed_request_reveal_tab/) has what you are looking for. With iframe pages, you have to do this with server code as Facebook will send post variables to your page with anonymous info about the user including their language and whether they are a fan or not.  Once they like the page, the page will refresh and you will know that they are a fan via the same post variable information.

Also, the FBML tabs are deprecated and you will want to convert them over to iframes when you have the time before Facebook kills them.